# MVC: Include classes in a component

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, mvc

So, for example, I have 3 classes: Division, Employee, Task.
Every task has an employee assigned to it and every employee belongs to a division.
Currently I need 4 views:

- a list of tasks assigned to a selected employee,
- a list of employees working on a selected task,
- a list of tasks an employee from a selected divison has worked on,
- a main list that will show a list of task with an amount of employees it was assigned to.

Outside of joomla if I need to get, for example, a list of tasks assigned to an employee, I just do something like:

```
$employee = new employee($id_of_employee);
$tasks = $employee->get_tasks();
```

So what is the best way to integrate it with joomla? Can I include my classes in a component or I'll have to redevelop it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You can simply include and instantiate your classes and interact with them the standalone PHP way you are used to - yes that is not a problem and Joomla doesn't restrict your ability to that - this approach gives you less to rewrite of your original code.

However if you were up for a challenge, you could refactor your code classes - which are actually models, and create a Model that extends JModelItem from them that Joomla could consume in its views.

[Full Official Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_model_to_the_site_part/en) on creating a Joomla 3.x Extension is available for this.

Comment: Ok... So, if my class extends another one, can a model extend another model? And can I call another model from a model?

Comment: yes yes and yes. Basic PHP 101 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following code -

```
require_once(JPATH_SITE_COMPONENT.'/helpers/your.class.php');
YOURCLASS::do();
```

or

```
$instance = new Yourclass();
$instance->do();
```

You can also use a static class with inherited methods like:

```
YOURCLASS::$subclass->do();
```

You can also inherit or extend Joomla classes (check the documentation) and please use Joomla's native functions for mailing or database management.

*If you use php files with Joomla, please put the following line at the top of every file to prevent external access to your scripts:*

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
```